# Writing nextjs generated on custom CDN

Tags: next.js, cdn

I am deploying my nextjs application on ec2 instance as my all other services are deployed on es2 so it would be easy for me to manage in terms of billing.

I have following type of pages:

- SSG
- SSR
- ISR

I can easily upload SSG pages over cdn after building nextjs application.

But, how can i upload ISR pages on CDN too, since they will be generated at run time and there is no hook available in nextjs which allows us to trigger after updating any ISR page?

Is there someone faced any similar problem or have any solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Next.js and Vercel:

- https://nextjs.org/docs
- https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/overview
- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration

Implement your own mechanism:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html

Options for ISR:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching
- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-recommended
- https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering

you can us AWS Lambda and AWS S3 as static storage instead of CDN.pre-render the pages and then use AWS Lambda to handle page requests and updates.

In the Next.js application, use getStaticProps with a validation key to specify the number of seconds for each regeneration attempt.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    // Next.js will attempt to re-generate the page:
    // - When a request comes in
    // - At most once every second
    revalidate: 1, // In seconds
  }
}
```

Use AWS Lambda function to serve pages. When the Lambda function is triggered, it would:
Check if a static page exists in an S3 bucket.
If the page is not "expired", show static page.
If the none of the above two, call your Next.js server to generate a new page and store this in S3.

example AWS Lambda function, using AWS SDK for JavaScript:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const BUCKET_NAME = 'your-s3-bucket-name';

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let pagePath = event.path;
    let staticPageKey = `static-pages${pagePath}.html`;
    
    try {
        // Try to get the static page from S3
        let data = await S3.getObject({ Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, Key: staticPageKey }).promise();

        // Here you'd also check if the page is "expired" based on your own logic

        // If the page exists and is valid, return it
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: data.Body.toString('utf-8'),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 'NoSuchKey') {
            // If the page doesn't exist in S3, generate it

            // Call your Next.js server to generate the page
            let response = await fetch(`https://your-next-js-server.com${pagePath}`);
            let pageHtml = await response.text();

            // Store the generated page in S3
            await S3.putObject({
                Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                Key: staticPageKey,
                Body: pageHtml,
                ContentType: 'text/html',
            }).promise();

            return {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: pageHtml,
            };
        } else {
            // If there was an error other than NoSuchKey, re-throw it
            throw error;
        }
    }
};
```

I would also look in to these solutions for your use case:

Using React with AWS Amplify: AWS Amplify has a feature called Server-Side Rendering (SSR). With it, you can use React to generate HTML on the server side, improving load times and SEO. AWS Amplify also has features for hosting, functions, APIs, and more.

Static Site Generation: You can generate static HTML pages from your React application using libraries like react-snap or react-static.